# distinct operation for datatable in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I have one DataTable  with three columns "HOUSE_BILL_KEY","HOUSE_BILL_SRC_ID" and "SRC_RCRD_ID" and has data as shown

[image]

I want only distinct values from datatable like 
[image]

how I will do it in behind the code?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to do that in the SQL query that you're using to populate your `dtCntnrHoubill` table. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUSE_BILL_KEY, HOUSE_BILL_SRC_ID, SRC_RCRD_ID
FROM dtCntnrHoubill
```

But if you really want it in code behind, you can use LINQ:

```
Dim distinctResults = dtCntnrHoubill.Distinct()
```

Comment: i can not change SQL query. need to do in vb.net itself . how i will use LINQ ? could you please give me example?

Comment: I already did, try the last line in my answer. You need `imports System.Linq`.